# weird for loop behaviour in firefox 3.5.3

Tags: javascript, firefox, for-loop

I maybe doing something wrong, but this seems quite weird to me:

```
for(i=1; i < 5; i++){ alert(i) }
```

in before mentioned firefox version gives me five counts of i. the question simply is: what the hell?

thanks!

**SOLUTION: ok, it was my own mistake. i actually had an alert after the one in the loop which displayed number 5 :)
thanks all who were ready to help and sorry for wasting your time.**

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. When I execute this, I get 4 alerts, with 1, 2, 3, and 4, as I would expect. Is that not what you are getting?

Comment: no, i am getting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. that's why i asked.

Comment: No, you're not. I don't even think you exist.

Answer (score 1):

I pasted `javascript:for(i=1; i < 5; i++){ alert(i) }` into my Firefox 3.5.3 address bar and it correctly alerted four times, 1-4.

Comment: yes, i get 5 counts. i was hoping it was a firefox issue, but since you guys are getting correct results, i'll have to search for other cause. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does your browser, in the page where you're seeing this problem, also give you five counts when you use a variable name other than "i"?  Does it do it when you explicitly declare a local "i" like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; ++i) alert(i);
```

?

Comment: i will definitely check that when i'm back home. good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the first value of `i`? What will be the last value of `i`, according to the loop conditional of `i < 5`?

Comment: the first value i 1. last value, if i < 5 should be 4. hence i expect 4 counts, right?

Answer (score 0):

It should only loop 4 times:

Granted yes, this is C++ code its the same concept:

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
                cout << i << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}


$ ./test
1
2
3
4

I guess I am not understanding exactly what the question is.

Comment: i am getting 5 alerts. which is obviously not correct. i have assumed this was a firefox issue, since IE is behaving as expected. but since people above tried the code and it worked, i have to find other cause. thanks for your help though! :)

Comment: Do you have any plugins or addons installed? I would try Firefox in safe mode: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Safe+Mode
I know the Skype plugin will insert its own Javascript code for making phone numbers click able on a page.

Comment: i have personas and firebug plugins. i thought of that as well, because it's really weird and the observation persists no matter what values i take. it simply overrides the < sign and takes the next value. anyway, i'll report again once i have turned the plugins off.